# How to apply chi-square distance on categorical dataset?

Tags: python, distance, categorical-data, chi-squared

I want to apply chi-square distance on a categorical dataset (219 x 55).
As I understand, categorical data must be encoded first before applying the chi-square formula ([reference](http://www.econ.upf.edu/%7Emichael/stanford/maeb4.pdf), P.10).
The formula for chi-square distance is as follow:

[image]

Where the row totals is denoted
[image]
and the column totals are
[image].

I am struggling to understand what sort of output I will be getting from applying this formula to my dataset. Is it a matrix of distances between rows that symmetrical across the diagonal (similar to the one found in the reference)?

Or is it a matrix with the same proportion of my dataset but each value is substituted with the distance?

Finally, is there a method for chi-square distance in python?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a Python package implementing the $\chi^2$ distance, but the [TraMineR package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TraMineR/index.html) in R implements it (the `biofam.chi` functions). That function takes in an `m x n` matrix and returns an `m x m` matrix symmetrical across the diagonal:

```
library(TraMineR)

data(biofam)
biofam.seq <- seqdef(biofam[501:600, 10:25])

dim(biofam.seq)
[1] 100 16

biofam.chi.full <- seqdist(biofam.seq, method = "CHI2",
                           step = max(seqlength(biofam.seq)))
dim(biofam.chi.full)
[1] 100 100

isSymmetric(biofam.chi.full)
[1] TRUE
```